# Why after setOnTouchListener does not work the other (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Why the orders after `setOnTouchListener` do not work ?

For example :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {
    public RelativeLayout MYLL=null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MYLL=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.MYL);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Begin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        MYLL.setOnTouchListener(this);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "End", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;//or true 
    }


}
```

When activated `setOnTouchListener` View a message "In" 
But why after the message "In" does not  following the other message "End"(In -> End) why ?

Comment: Why would you get an "End" toast after "In"..? `onTouch` is called when a touch event occurs, which can happen at any time, e.g. long after execution of `onCreate` has finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnCreate is called once in the beginning of your example.
Showing the Toast "Begin", setting the OnTouchListener and then showing the Toast "End".

The OnTouchListener is called on every Touch after being set, NOT when it is first set.
If you wanted the "End" Toast to be called after the "In" Toast, you would need to show the Toast from inside the OnTouchListener after the "In" Toast.

Answer (score 0):

End will be shown only once when the activity is created not every time but In will be shown up as many time as you touch that view, If you want to show end every time when In shows up put that toast right after In, other wise End will be shown up only once i.e onCreate().

Comment: Vote up please ?